# property not exist on type - vue with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to convert the js code to ts. My attempt is as below.

```
<script lang="ts">
 export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isShow: false as boolean
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openCalendar() : void {
      this.isShow = true;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

But when I run the app it's throws an error in the console saying Property `isShow` does not exist on type `{open(): void;}`. Where I was got wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get types inference try to wrap your options with `Vue.extend({})` :

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'  
export default Vue.extend({
data() {
    return {
      isShow: false as boolean
    }
  }
  methods: {
    openCalendar() : void {
      this.isShow = true;
    },
 },
})
</script>
```